# Build a full adder using 2 4:2:1 MUXes and the constants 0 and 1

Tags: cpu-architecture

A question in computer structures,

Build a full adder using 2 4:2:1 MUXes and the constants 0 and 1. Use minimum amount of constants.

Obviously this question is solvable using not gates too, but I am interested in the question without them.

Comment: By 4:2:1 mux, do you mean something with four inputs, two control bits, and one output?

Comment: Yes it is, 4 inputs, 2 control and 1 output.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get to use NOT gates?

Comment: @Vadiklk - So what came of the complaint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean a four-input mux, you can do (to add `a`, `b`, and `c`):

```
carry = mux(/* controls */ a, b, /* inputs */ 0, c, c, 1);
```

I'm not sure how to get `sum` without some other gate.  One option is (with AND and OR):

```
sum = mux(/* controls */ carry, a, /* inputs */ b|c, 0, 1, b&c);
```

With XOR (probably obvious):

```
sum = mux(/* controls */ a, b^c, /* inputs */ 0, 1, 1, 0);
```

Here's a sketch of why you can't do it with two muxes:

Since you have two muxes and two outputs, each mux must produce one output; thus, you need to compute `sum` from `carry` or compute `carry` from `sum`.  You can't compute `sum` with just the three inputs without a NOT gate, and so you need to compute `carry` first.  You can do that; then you need to get `sum` from the inputs and `carry`.  Since the inputs are symmetric, the mux for `sum` can have its controls be either two inputs or one input and `carry`.  The first case fails for the same reason that you can't compute `sum` first.  Looking at the truth table and all possible combinations of `carry` and one input (call it `a`), there is no way to compute `sum` uniquely for the case where `carry` and `a` are the same using only one variable or constant as the input to each data input of the `sum` mux.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but I can do any one of them with the use of only 2 MUXes but, that is exactly the problem. I need more MUXes or not gates.

Comment: See the latest edits; I think I put down basically all of the combinations.

Comment: Basically you are saying that it is impossible?

Comment: @Vadiklk: I think so, at least with only two muxes and no other gates.  For tests, though, you might want to put down what you can do (`carry` with one mux, `sum` with two muxes or one mux and some other gate) to get at least partial credit.

Comment: Thanks, I was 99% sure it is impossible just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a simple little C# program to check every possible input combination, and it fails to find a solution. So, unless I made some kind of program error, there is no solution to this problem.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool[] aValues = new bool[] { false, false, false, false, true, true, true, true };
        bool[] bValues = new bool[] { false, false, true, true, false, false, true, true };
        bool[] cValues = new bool[] { false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true };
        bool[] carryValues = new bool[] { false, false, false, true, false, true, true, true };
        bool[] constantFalse = new bool[] { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false };
        bool[] constantTrue = new bool[] { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true };

        bool[] sumValues = new bool[] { false, true, true, false, true, false, false, true };

        bool[][] allInputs = new bool[][] { aValues, bValues, cValues, carryValues, constantFalse, constantTrue };

        for (int controlOneIndex = 0; controlOneIndex < allInputs.Length; controlOneIndex++)
            for (int controlTwoIndex = 0; controlTwoIndex < allInputs.Length; controlTwoIndex++)
                for (int inputOneIndex = 0; inputOneIndex < allInputs.Length; inputOneIndex++)
                    for (int inputTwoIndex = 0; inputTwoIndex < allInputs.Length; inputTwoIndex++)
                        for (int inputThreeIndex = 0; inputThreeIndex < allInputs.Length; inputThreeIndex++)
                            for (int inputFourIndex = 0; inputFourIndex < allInputs.Length; inputFourIndex++)
                            {
                                for (int calculationIndex = 0; calculationIndex < sumValues.Length; calculationIndex++)
                                {
                                    if (MuxResult(allInputs[controlOneIndex][calculationIndex],
                                                allInputs[controlTwoIndex][calculationIndex],
                                                allInputs[inputOneIndex][calculationIndex],
                                                allInputs[inputTwoIndex][calculationIndex],
                                                allInputs[inputThreeIndex][calculationIndex],
                                                allInputs[inputFourIndex][calculationIndex]) != sumValues[calculationIndex])
                                    {
                                        goto tryNextValue;
                                    }
                                }
                                Console.WriteLine("Success: controls: {0} {1}   inputs: {2} {3} {4} {5}",
                                    controlOneIndex, controlTwoIndex, inputOneIndex, inputTwoIndex, inputThreeIndex, inputFourIndex);
                            tryNextValue: ;
                            }
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static bool MuxResult(bool controlOne, bool controlTwo, bool inputOne, bool inputTwo, bool inputThree, bool inputFour)
    {
        if (controlOne)
        {
            if (controlTwo)
                return inputFour;
            else
                return inputTwo;
        }
        else
        {
            if (controlTwo)
                return inputThree;
            else
                return inputOne;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you were 20 seconds late to get the "right answer", you deserve a vote up at least.

Answer (score 1):

```
A B Cin S cout
0 0 0   0 0
0 0 1   1 0
0 1 0   1 0
0 1 1   0 1
1 0 0   1 0
1 0 1   0 1
1 1 0   0 1
1 1 1   1 1
```

By taking `A`, as the selection line to two 2*1 muxs we have in the first mux in input number 0 `B XOR Cin` in input number 1 `B XNOR Cin` -> this mux for `S`
in the second mux in input number 0 we have `B AND Cin` in input number 1 we have `B OR Cin`
-> this for `Cout` .

Answer (score -1):

A Full adder in VB

```
Class fullAdder

    Private _A As Boolean
    Private _B As Boolean
    Private _Cin As Boolean
    Private _Sum As Boolean
    Private _Cout As Boolean

    Public Sub New()
        Me.A = False
        Me.B = False
        Me.Cin = False
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetInputs(a As Boolean, b As Boolean, cIn As Boolean)
        Me.A = a
        Me.B = b
        Me.Cin = cIn
    End Sub

    'Inputs           Outputs
    'A  B  Cin        Cout  S
    '0  0   0         0     0
    '1  0   0         0     1
    '0  1   0         0     1
    '1  1   0         1     0
    '0  0   1         0     1
    '1  0   1         1     0
    '0  1   1         1     0
    '1  1   1         1     1 

    Public Sub DoAdd()
        'debugIn()
        Dim ABxor As Boolean = Me.A Xor Me.B
        Me.Sum = ABxor Xor Me.Cin
        Dim ABxorAndCin As Boolean = ABxor And Me.Cin
        Dim ABand As Boolean = Me.A And Me.B
        Me.Cout = ABxorAndCin Or ABand
        'debugOut()
    End Sub

    Private Sub debugIn()
        Debug.WriteLine("'I {0} {1} {2}", Me.A, Me.B, Me.Cin)
    End Sub

    Private Sub debugOut()
        Debug.WriteLine("'O {0} {1}", Me.Cout, Me.Sum)
        Debug.WriteLine("")
    End Sub

    Public Property Sum() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._Sum
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me._Sum = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Cout() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._Cout
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me._Cout = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property A() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._A
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me._A = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property B() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._B
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me._B = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Cin() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._Cin
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me._Cin = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Could you write it in a way the one with the right answer wrote it?

Comment: So you want me to duplicate the code that is already written?  This was just meant to be a full adder simulation.

Comment: I do not understand how does this look in a computer structure way.

Comment: An Visual Basic implementation of a full adder may be interesting trivia, but it does nothing to address the actual question asked. Perhaps if the implementation demonstrates a pair of MUXes that can alone implement a full adder, or if it is used to demonstrate that such a thing is impossible, then it would be on-topic. If that is the case, then the fact or method should be spelled out. But the OP presumably already knows how to implement a full-adder, and has not indicated a need to do so unless the implementation uses only two MUXes.

Comment: I need an implementation of a full adder using only 2 Muxes and 0's and 1's.

Comment: A reference to the MUXes being used would be helpful?